# Html forms in Outlook cause security violation

Tags: html, forms, outlook, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a simple form that I send in user's emails for resetting their password. It works in the Gmail client, but it doesn't work in Outlook.

```
<form action="${login_url}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="${email}">
  <input type="hidden" name="pass" id="pass" value="${password}">
  <input type="submit" value="Password Reset">
</form>
```

In the console, I get the following error:

> Refused to send form data to
> 'https://path/to/post-endpoint' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action
> *.officeapps.live.com".

Do I have to register my endpoint with MS Office or something? Or are there some HTML tags that I need to send in the email?

Comment: why are you emailing them an HTML form? Why don't you rather send them a link to a page on the site to reset password using the same form. If they turn HTML off on their mail client it will not work either way. Some people don't allow HTML emails. If you really need to send the form why dont you place the actual URL for `${login_url}`. Surely that will stay the same always.

Comment: These are AWS Cognito accounts, and I'm using a lambda function for rendering the invite email. I don't have direct access to the password, only a placeholder. Otherwise, I could generate an encypted JWT token using javascript. This solution requires HTML only. I can't send the password in a GET url, but I could send it securely via POST body.

Gmail worked so nicely, but if many email clients have the same security issue, this might not be a workable solution.